# Segmentation fault when using struct in C

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, clang

Why do I get Segmentation fault here? I'm very new to C and it's really hard for me.
I googled much and found out that it have to be working normally.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct school
{
    int schoolNum;
    int year;
    int gradNum;
    int univNum;
};

int main()
{
    struct school schools[5] = {
        114, 2020, 470, 300,
        86, 2019, 545, 450,
        231, 2020, 340, 320,
        113, 2020, 435, 395,
        55, 2019, 395, 380
    };

    printf('%d\n', schools[0].gradNum);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `"` instead of `'` for string literals.

Comment: The single quotes in your `printf` call are wrong. use double quotes for your format string. You should get a compiler warnings about the problem. (Enable all warnings.)

Comment: thank you, that was really stupid mistake

Comment: You may also like to add 4 pairs of braces `{ ... }` in your initializer array of structures.

Comment: A decent compiler should emit a warning about multi.character literals, and if not then you need to enable more warnings.

Comment: when compiling, enable the warnings. Then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results.

Answer (score 3):

There's two errors in your code, as said in the comments, you need to replace single quotes by double quotes in your printf call.
Then you need to add braces pairs to enclose each school instance, as below:

```
struct school schools[5] = {
        {114, 2020, 470, 300},
        {86, 2019, 545, 450},
        {231, 2020, 340, 320},
        {113, 2020, 435, 395},
        {55, 2019, 395, 380}
    };
```

Comment: In fact, omitting the inner braces is not an error per se, but adding them highly recommended for readability.